# React-Hook-Form register function without prop spreading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

I am using React Hook Form to register data form an input like so:

```
<input
          className="block w-full box-border rounded-lg mb-5 text-sm p-[1em] border-[1px] border-gray-400 h-[46.8px]"
          id="passwordInput"
          {...register('password', { required: true })}
          type="password"
        />
```

Its working great and fine until the moment I implement eslint with airbnb rules into my project.
Eslint pushes the idea that prop spreading should not be used because we might use props that are not even neccesary.

```
Prop spreading is forbiddeneslintreact/jsx-props-no-spreading
```

Is there a way to not use an ignore func to ignore the message from eslint and use the register function from react hook form without spreading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according to documentation, you can use this:

```
const { onChange, onBlur, name, ref } = register('firstName'); 
// include type check against field path with the name you have supplied.
        
<input 
  onChange={onChange} // assign onChange event 
  onBlur={onBlur} // assign onBlur event
  name={name} // assign name prop
  ref={ref} // assign ref prop
/>
// same as above
<input {...register('firstName')} />
```

https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register/

---

edit: more inputs

```
const firstNameReg = register('firstName');
const lastNameReg = register('lastName'); 
        
return <><input 
  onChange={firstNameReg.onChange} 
  onBlur={firstNameReg.onBlur} 
  name={firstNameReg.name} 
  ref={firstNameReg.ref} 
/>
<input 
  onChange={lastNameReg.onChange} 
  onBlur={lastNameReg.onBlur} 
  name={lastNameReg.name} 
  ref={lastNameReg.ref} 
/><>;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked like a piece of cake! Just one more question, if I would like to make this register for another input how would that be possible if all the register function are under 'username'?

Comment: you can rename returned variables:`
`const {onChange:surnameChange, onBlur:surnameBlur} = register('surname')`

Comment: or you can skip destructuring and use dot notation:
`const firstNameRegister = register('firstName)`
and then pass it to input
`<input onChange={firstNameRegister.onChange} ...`
and then use it like this for every input

Comment: I edited my answer with example :)

Comment: Woooow, thank you a lot again, you just fixed my annoying problem. Youre the man wraithy :D